# How to call Export PDF with Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd....URL from BackEnd C# Code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, report, rdlc

My Aim is to call ExportBaseUrl Link , that is given by Rdlc Exprot PDF button , on C# side, i want to do that because there are 285 reports and each one have diff parameters so this will take a lot time.

I have worked on one solution but that take 15 min to load 2 page RDLC to pdf.
Its taking time due to Response coming late or some deadlock is happening,

This is what i am doing.
JS file

```
  var reportViewerName = ControlName; //Name attribute of report viewer control.
    var src_url = $find(reportViewerName)._getInternalViewer().ExportUrlBase + 'PDF';

    var contentDisposition = 'AlwaysInline'; //Content Disposition instructs the server to either return the PDF being requested as an attachment or a viewable report.
    var src_new = src_url.replace(/(ContentDisposition=).*?(&)/, '$1' + contentDisposition + '$2');


    window.open("/printPDF.asx?url=" + encodeURIComponent("http://localhost:5402"+src_new));
```

PrintPDF.aspx File is like this

```
        using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Action;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApp.WebAPI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for printPDF
    /// </summary>
    public class printPDF : IHttpHandler
    {

        public  void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Hello World");


            string url = context.Request.QueryString["url"];

            // Download data.
             DownloadFile(url, context.Server.MapPath("~/pdf/pdffile.pdf"), context.Request).Wait();

            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(context.Server.MapPath("~/pdf/pdffile.pdf")), new PdfWriter(context.Server.MapPath("~/pdf/pdffileAuto.pdf")));
            // add content
            PdfAction action = PdfAction.CreateJavaScript("this.print({bUI: true, bSilent: true, bShrinkToFit: true});");
            pdfDoc.GetCatalog().SetOpenAction(action);
            pdfDoc.Close();

            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "AlwaysInline;filename=\"FileName.pdf\"");

            context.Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/pdf/pdffileAuto.pdf")));

            context.Response.Flush();

            context.Response.End();

        }
        public async Task DownloadFile(string url, string destinationPath, HttpRequest req)
        {

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";

            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-IN");
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
            request.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            Uri target = new Uri("http://localhost:5402/");

            foreach (String item in req.Cookies)
            {
                request.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(item, req.Cookies[item].Value) { Domain = target.Host });
            }
await request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(t1 =>   
            {
                using (var responseStream = t1.Result.GetResponseStream())
                {


                    if (responseStream == null)
                        return;

                    int bufferSize = 1024;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    int bytesRead = 0;

                    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(destinationPath))
                    {
                        while ((bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != 0)
                        {
                            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
                t1.Result.Close();
            });

        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

line
**await request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(t1 =>**

with async and without async takes around 15 min time once, second time it go to deadlock/Freez

also i had to add cookie due to the url was throwing 500 internal server error.

And if i call url direct on browser it runs in 1 sec.

So if anyone know what is issue or can help then that would be really big help.

Thanks for Help in Advance.

Ok

> I found what issue is,

Issue is tab request PrintPDF.aspx and that page request other URL on same site.
So untill PrintPDF.aspx response complete to tab that (HttpWebRequest) is not being called.

Any reason why? i set maxconnection in web.config though

Comment: I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to determine if the delays are in the client or server. How may webpages are you opening.  Sometimes I open two clients one for the main page and the second for any child pages.

Comment: Only 2 tabs open,one for RDLC and one for printPDFm, thanks i will try wireshark

Comment: The may be a firewall checking contents of downloaded file for viruses which is slowing everything down.

Comment: i tested with firewall off,still same,funny thing is if i use url direct then it loads in 1 sec

Comment: Use sniffer, user sniffer, use sniffer.  Compare 1 sec result with c# code.  Also output time inside code so you can compare sniffer and code time to isolate where issue is occurring.

Comment: Found what issue is.Read Last part of question.

Comment: The write PDF is not in the async method.

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix it by making 2 diff files, first ASPX file which show page and generate pdf in thread and on page load call Ashx file which checks if file is generated or not, if generated then return file.

there was not other way, so i fixed it by 2 links redirect call.

Thank Everyone who helped me.